# Analyzing repeated categories from multiple columns in R

Tags: r

I have a dataset of companies grouped by categories. Some companies have multiple categories, which can repeat across multiple columns. I'd like to know how to analyze them based on categories (such as the mean value of each category). Here's a sample data.frame

```
a <- factor(c("cat1", "cat2", "cat3", "cat4", "cat2"))
b <- factor(c("cat5", "cat4", "cat2", "cat1", "NA"))
comp <- factor(c("company1", "company2", "company3", "company4","company5"))
score <- c(1, -1, 2, -2, 1.5) 
df <- data.frame(a, b, comp, score)

#     a    b     comp score
#1 cat1 cat5 company1   1.0
#2 cat2 cat4 company2  -1.0
#3 cat3 cat2 company3   2.0
#4 cat4 cat1 company4  -2.0
#5 cat2   NA company5   1.5
```

One task I'd like to know is the mean value of each category. From eyeing this simple dataset, I know the mean value of cat1 would be -0.5. I have some rough approaches, but nothing that follows through on the task:

1. I thought about applying melt to the data.frame, so that each instance of a category factor would have its own row (in this case, the dimensions would be 10x1, each category-score pair for each row).
2. I also thought about using dplyr and grouping by unique names, from something like

   ```
   mynames <- unique(c(levels(a), levels(b)))
   ```

but, dplyr requires grouping to be a vector in the data.frame (unless there's some way to group by a pattern or factor level that i'm unware of, which would be great!)

3. Finally, I may not need to make a separate dataframe. Perhaps there's a way to use apply to apply fuctions, such as mean, to unique category levels.

Thank you for the help!

Comment: Are you concerned that melting to a long format would take too long on your actual dataset?  It seems like this task would be really easy on a long-format dataset...

Answer (score 2):

Following your idea of getting all categories, we can create the boolean columns for each category, and them take the mean of only those which have that category. For example:

```
a <- factor(c("cat1", "cat2", "cat3", "cat4", "cat2"))
b <- factor(c("cat5", "cat4", "cat2", "cat1", NA)) #NA, not "NA" or it will be a new level
score <- c(1, -1, 2, -2, 1.5) 
df <- data.frame(a, b, score)
```

We create a vector with all the categories:

```
cats <- unique(c(levels(df$a), levels(df$b)))
```

Then, for each category we check, for each row, wether the category is present or not in `a` or `b`:

```
catcols <- sapply(cats, function(i) {
  sapply(1:nrow(df), function(j) {
    return(i %in% df$a[j] | i %in% df$b[j])
  })
})
```

This returns a matrix, which we can add to our dataframe:

```
> catcols
      cat1  cat2  cat3  cat4  cat5
[1,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
[2,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
[3,] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
[4,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
[5,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE

> df2 <- cbind(df, catcols)
```

Now we just have to take the mean for each category, subsetting only those rows which are `TRUE` for the category:

```
means <- sapply(cats, function(i) {
  mean(df2[df2[,i],"score"])
})

means

#       cat1       cat2       cat3       cat4       cat5 
# -0.5000000  0.8333333  2.0000000 -1.5000000  1.0000000
```

**Edit**

I couldn't figure out a much better alternative, but was able to improve the code a little bit. Using random data about the size you mentioned:

```
ncats <- 500
allcats <- paste0("cat", 1:ncats)
nrow <- 50000
ncol <- 26
set.seed(1)
bigdf <- data.frame(replicate(ncol, sample(allcats, nrow, replace = TRUE)), score=rnorm(nrow))
```

The code:

```
scorecol <- which(names(bigdf) == "score")

catcols <- data.frame(sapply(allcats, function(i) {
  apply(bigdf[,-scorecol], 1, function(j) i %in% j)
}))

means <- sapply(allcats, function(i) {
  mean(bigdf[catcols[,i],"score"])
})
```

This took 195 seconds for me, and was about 30% of the time of the previous approach (microbenchmarked with smaller data). The results were:

```
> head(means)
        cat1         cat2         cat3         cat4         cat5         cat6 
0.0019851051 0.0006465704 0.0066345735 0.0126089999 0.0135545455 0.0253983216
```

I tried looking for a `dplyr` alternative but couldn't find anything useful. I'm sure there's a faster approach using `data.table`, but I'm not very good with the package yet.

Comment: ok awesome! I probably should have made clearer that this is for a larger dataset (50K rows). I tried out your function, catcols, and it keeps on running--and that's just for 2 categories. I have about 26 columns and 500 levels in the full dataset. So, you definitely solved the sample df but i'm having trouble applying it :) How might i apply this to a larger dataset?

Comment: @tom The nested loop definetly isn't a good approach to large data. I'll see if I can think of something better.

Comment: @tom I added an alternative, isn't much better though.

Answer (score 1):

Using melt and ddply functions:

```
df_melt <- melt(df, id.vars = c("comp", "score"), measure.vars = c("a", "b"))
ddply( .data = df_melt, .variables = .(value), summarise, mean = round(mean(score), digits = 2) )
```

In this way it would also be easy to calculate other summary stats.

For the bigger dataset as per Molx:

```
# adding a hypothetical company column so that we do not deviate from the smaller dataset case above:
bigdf$comp <- paste("company", 1:50000, sep = "")

measure_vars <- names(bigdf)[-c(dim(bigdf)[2]-1, dim(bigdf)[2])]
bigdf_melt <- melt(bigdf, id.vars = c("comp", "score"), measure.vars = measure_vars)
# transform value column to an ordered factor so that ddply returns result in an ordered category fashion
bigdf_melt$value <- factor(bigdf_melt$value, levels = paste0("cat", 1:ncats), ordered = TRUE)

bigdf_mean <- ddply( .data = bigdf_melt, .variables = .(value), summarise, mean = round(mean(score), digits = 4) )
bigdf_mean
```